# Local density in SSH model

Tags: topology

Considering the usual SSH model defined on N sites and parametrized with $\delta $:
$$H = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{N-1} (1-\delta)\ c_{j,A}^{\dagger}\ c_{j,B} +(1+\delta)\ c_{j,B}^{\dagger}\ c_{j+1,A} + h.c $$

In the fully dimerized limit, i.e $\delta=1$, how would one compute the local density for each state ($<c_{j,\alpha}^{\dagger}c_{j,\alpha}> $)?

I know the hamiltonian matrix and can numerically compute its eigenvector but don't manage to find the link with the local density. I would like to obtain the same kind of graph as in Fig 1.b from the paper "Topological phases of a dimerized Fermi-Hubbard model for semiconductor nano-lattices" which proves that the zero energy states are mostly localized at the edges.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have obtained the Hamiltonian, and diagonalized it to get the ground state vector, you have presumably chosen a basis, and I would guess that it is labelling sites in real-space, as this is the most "natural" basis to take for a hopping Hamiltonian of this type. Is that right? In that case, the particle density at each point is given by $\rho(j) = |v(j)|^2$, where $v(j)$ is the $j$-th element of the vector you have. So typically $j=1$ is the left-most site, $j=2$ is its neighbor, etc, until you reach $j=N$ which is the rightmost site.

On a side-note, taking $\delta=1$ may give odd results, as the dimers are then completely decoupled from each other. I would start by taking increasingly small values of $\delta$ to see how the system evolves.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I chose to use the basis labelling the sites in real-space. I'll try to compute it that way $\delta\neq 0$ because the dimerized results indeed seem odd! But I fail to see how this computation is related to the average $<c_{j,\alpha}^{\dagger} c_{j,\alpha}> $. Maybe it's two different things but in that case I don't know how to compute the latter...

Comment: Ah, I interpreted your $\langle c_{j \alpha} ^\dagger c_{j \alpha} \rangle$ as being an expectation value, i.e. $\langle v | c_{j \alpha} ^\dagger c_{j \alpha} | v \rangle$. Are you instead taking an average, like averaging over the spatial sites $j$?

Comment: I would like to average over the states so you are probably right. I just have to select the eigenvector associated to a zero energy state and to try your method to deduce the local density. This should give something similar to the paper's figure, I hope. Thank you!